# Is any possible to override Angular Material Constants in select.ts?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I would like to fix select height via pass variable, but it is a constant in material code (select.ts).

[mat-select api](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#SELECT_ITEM_HEIGHT_EM)

[source code in Github : material2 / select.ts](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/select/select.ts#L114)

Is any possible to override that const using providers or other skill?

I know there are solution in custom css style:

1.Use ::ng-deep:

2.Use ViewEncapsulation

3.Set class style in style.css and !important

4.Use panelClass

But those solution are css , it will cause css pollution ?

```
::ng-deep .mat-option{
   height: 2.5em; 
}
```

```
mat-option{
   height: 2.5em !important;
}
```

Finally,if i can't override const in select.ts, using CSS may cause some unknown issue in future or it's fine in my case ?

Comment: its not css hackk.... its css...
if you want to overrride the css of those stuff that your solution...
I did it in every project I had in work and on the current system we are working on.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I fixed the word "css hack" to "css".  

I am using custom theming in ng-material, some style (likes max-height, line height ) they are not support.  I found some property in API docs, so there is the question here.

Answer (score 1):

finally I using code below in custom material theming rather than component's css.

```
mat-option{
   height: 2.5em !important;
}
```

[custom material theming](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components)

becasue I found 'Official Docs' and 'Official GitHub issue' reply that 'has never been supported.'

> https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/8054#issuecomment-339788633